# Integration Jbehave and LoggingSelenium

Tags: selenium, bdd, jbehave

There is a great library to generate reports in selenium, called [LoggingSelenium](http://loggingselenium.sourceforge.net/usage.html), that gives nice, detailed reports, like [this one](http://loggingselenium.sourceforge.net/samples/sampleResultSuccess.html)

Is there any way to integrate this library to jbehave (given that it uses selenium)?

or is there some way to obtain these kind of detailed reports for jbehave (at a selenium command level)?

Answer (score 0):

There probably is but I've not seen it done.  When configuring the running of JBehave, you will have a SeleniumConfiguration (if you create a maven project from the archetype, you can see a good default setup).  However, that uses Selenium 2 (aka WebDriver).  And there are typically Before/After steps to setup the WebDriver, given a WebDriverProvider (a JBehave class).  I've seen screenshot capture on failure - also done as a JBehave AfterStory method.

JBehave also has a StoryReporter interface for tracking events as the story is executed but that's not really what you are looking for.  This is more a configuration of the Selenium infrastructure.

Big question is if LoggingSelenium works with the WebDriver API.